# How to install MonoDevelop 2.4 from sources?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, installation, monodevelop

I've installed (./configure; make; sudo make install) Mono bunzip2 -df xsp-2.8 mono-2.8, libgdiplus-2.8, gtk-sharp-2.12.10, mono-addins-0.5, gnome-sharp-2.20.1 packages from ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources/

Then I've tried to install monodevelop-2.4, but it reports "configure: error: Cannot enable GNOME platform without gnome-sharp-2.0" (while gnome-sharp-2.0 IS installed).

How to overcome this?

I've found numerous posts on the Internet reporting the same problem, but no actual solution.

I run Ubuntu 10.10 x32. Ubuntu standard Mono packages (for Mono 2.6) were NOT installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gnome-sharp build is probably incomplete. gnome-sharp is composed by several assemblies, and one of them may have not been built due to missing dependencies.

To fix this, run ./configure again for gnome-sharp and make sure that at the end it says 'yes' for all assemblies. If it says 'no' for one of them, you'll have to install the required devel packages (see the NOTE shown by the configure script for a list of dependencies).